# Why is it necessary to install separate "graphviz" to use graphviz-module in Python?

Tags: python, installation, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to use `graphviz` in Python.

#### Research

When I read the tutorials on websites, they say installing `graphviz 2.38` from a [separate download page](https://graphviz.org/download/) is necessary.

Formerly this was the download-page's URL:
https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

#### Question

Why can't I just install graphviz using pip and use it?
Why is it necessary to download this file?

Comment: Because graphviz package in python a mere wrapper than allows you to use graphviz, that is written in C and is in itself a software